# VBA: Filter values and copy an offset

Tags: vba

I have been trying to do this but keep getting the error: `"Application Defined or Object defined error"` for the `.Offset` line. On the spreadsheet "Log Frame info" I want to find every row that has the value `Sustainability:*` in **column O** and copy the corresponding information in **column M** for that row. Then I want that information pasted to the spreadsheet "SPSE Tran" starting at cell **B73**. I know this is not in the code but, if possible, if should skip copying the **M column** if **M** is blank (even when there is `Sustainability:*` in **column O**.

```
Sub test()

Dim RngDest as Range

With Sheets("SPSE Tran")
    Set RngDest = .Range("B73")
End With

With Sheets("Log Frame Info").Range("O:O")
    .AutoFilter 1, "Sustainability:*"
    .Offset(1, -2).Copy RngDest
    .AutoFilter
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The `.Offset` command doesn't make sense in that context since you have selected a column ("O"). (You offset vertically when you have selected a column...)

Comment: Thanks for the help Sifu. I was able to make it work by limiting O to O1:O1000. Do you know how I can make it where it only copies when the offset (1,-2) has a value in it? (is not blank)

Comment: You can put an If statement. Something along this : `If Not Isempty({Offset cell}) Then 'Copying' End if`

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, the range needs to have a limit at the end because Excel has a limited amount of total rows. Consequently if you add the range O1:O1000 it works!